# check the input string name if one the text file or not, here is my code, but it is not work

Tags: java

My text file include:
Tom,Marry,Erick,Lok,Kevin,Ben,Sally

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{

   Scanner sc = new Scanner (new FileReader("name.txt"));
   String Name;
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Enter a name:");
   Name= in.nextLine();


   String name = null;
   while(sc.hasNext())
   {
    int i=0;
    name= sc.next();   
    String [] Str=name.split(",");

    if (Name.equals(Str[i]))
    {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    }       
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No");
    }
    if (i<Str.length)
    {
        i++;
    }

 }
```

i want to input a name, then display if in the text file or not. i tried many way, but still not work, help me please.

Comment: No,but i input Marry that is the second value of the text file, it will print "No", i don't know why

Comment: Java is case sensitive, `Name` is not a synonym for `name`.

Comment: You missed `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will check only the first word means `Tom` in the `String` array. If you want to check each word of array use `for` loop. If you input `Marry` then it will compare with `Tom` so answer `No`.

```
while(sc.hasNext())
   {
    name= sc.next();   
    String [] Str=name.split(",");
    for(String s: Str){
    if (Name.equals(s))
    {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    }       
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No");
    }
    }//for missed. otherwise it will check only the first word in the String array
    }
```

**Edit:**
One more way to check

```
while(sc.hasNext())
   {
    name= sc.next(); //get each line from text file
    String [] Str=name.split(",");
    if(Arrays.asList(Str).contains(Name))//check whether Name contains or not
    System.out.println("Yes");//If array contains the given input then Yes
    else
    System.out.println("No");//Otherwise No
    }
```

Comment: i try it ,but the code will print Yes No No No No No No

Comment: Since it (Name) is comparing with the each value in String array. See my edit also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{

   Scanner sc = new Scanner (new FileReader("name.txt"));
   String Name;
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Enter a name:");
   Name= in.nextLine();


   String name = null;

    name= sc.next();  

    String [] Str=name.split(",");
   int flag=0;
   for(String sd:Str)
   {    

    if (Name.equals(sd))
    {

        flag=1;
        break;
    }       
    else
    {
       continue;
    }


   }
   if(flag==1) 

   System.out.println("yes");
   else 
   System.out.println("no");

   }
}
```